# How to make clickable table column header in Wicket

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I am using AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable for table creation.

For sortable columns, currently wicket creates ajax link under each column name to make it
as clickable.

But I want to make the complete column header as clickable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add some CSS to make the `<a>` in the column header a block element

```
tr.headers th a {
    display:block   
}
```